# Combine duplicate layouts into one layout on Gboard's multilingual support

Tags: keyboard, languages, gboard

I have been a SwiftKey user for a long time and for various reasons I am looking to switch to Gboard (one thing is the search feature). However, there is one thing that still keeps me to SwiftKey.

I generally use English, French and Greek layouts. I really enjoy the multilingual layout feature of SwiftKey and I was hoping that Gboard would do it in a similar way. However, this is not the case.

SwiftKey and Gboard both unify EN and FR layouts. However, SwiftKey only really displays one option (fr/en) in contrast with Gboard that displays two options: fr/en and en/fr. I don't know the purpose of this, but it means that I have to change two layouts in order to write Greek, which I don't really like.

Has anyone found any solution to this "problem"?